# Mailman administrative requests failing - web interface

Tags: apache-2.4, mailman

I am running a server that handles a site (www.example.org) and will also run email through mail2.example.org.  I am running the web interface for mailman through server.example.org, which is also the server name.

Mailman is not handling the administrative requests such as approving and discarding submissions.

This is my **mm_cfg.py** file:

```
from socket import *
try:
    fqdn = getfqdn()
except:
    fqdn = 'mm_cfg_has_unknown_host_domains'

DEFAULT_URL_HOST = 'server.example.org'
DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST = 'mail2.example.org'
add_virtualhost(DEFAULT_URL_HOST,DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST)
VIRTUAL_MAILMAN_LOCAL_DOMAIN = 'localhost'

MTA = 'Postfix'
POSTFIX_STYLE_VIRTUAL_DOMAINS = [ 'mail2.example.org' ]
```

When I try to Approve or Discard messages through the web interface, nothing happens, the page reloads unchanged.

**mailman.conf**

```
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/
<Directory /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/>
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>


Alias /pipermail/ /var/lib/mailman/archives/public/
<Directory /var/lib/mailman/archives/public>
    Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    AddDefaultCharset Off
</Directory>

RedirectMatch ^/mailman[/]*$ https://server.example.org/mailman/listinfo
```

I don't see any errors in any log files.

> /usr/lib/mailman/bin/check_perms -f
>   No problems found
>
> /usr/lib/mailman/bin/withlist -l -a -r fix_url
>   Importing fix_url...
>   Running fix_url.fix_url()... 
>   Loading list mailman (locked) 
>   Saving list
>   Loading list all (locked) 
>   Saving list 
>   Loading list siteadmin (locked)
>   Saving list Finalizing

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in **/var/log/mailman/error**

**/var/log/mailman/error**

```
admin(23367): [----- Mailman Version: 2.1.15 -----] 
admin(23367): [----- Traceback ------] 
admin(23367): Traceback (most recent call last):
admin(23367):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/scripts/driver", line 112, in run_main
admin(23367):     main()
admin(23367):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admindb.py", line 180, in main
admin(23367):     process_form(mlist, doc, cgidata)
admin(23367):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Cgi/admindb.py", line 756, in process_form
admin(23367):     forward, forwardaddr)
admin(23367):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/ListAdmin.py", line 167, in HandleRequest
admin(23367):     forward, addr)
admin(23367):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/ListAdmin.py", line 270, in __handlepost
admin(23367):     msg = readMessage(path)
admin(23367):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/ListAdmin.py", line 604, in readMessage
admin(23367):     fp = open(path)
admin(23367): IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/mailman/data/heldmsg-all-11.pck'
> Loading list siteadmin (locked)
> Saving list Finalizing
```

It was a file ownership / permissions issue.

Permissions for **/var/lib/mailman/data** are:

```
ls -lat /var/lib/mailman/data
total 20
drwxrwsr-x. 2 mailman mailman    74 Jul 21 06:48 .
-rw-------. 1 mailman mailman 17774 Jul 21 06:47 owner-bounces.mbox
-rw-r--r--. 1 mailman mailman     0 Jul 19 22:10 transport-mailman
drwxrwsr-x. 6 mailman mailman    55 Jul 13 20:37 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mailman mailman    25 Jul 13 20:37 sitelist.cfg -> /etc/mailman/sitelist.cfg
```

It's working.